# I can't delete the selected row in a gridView from DataSet

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, dataset

I have a gridView in my form and a button which delete the selected row in this gridView and also from the DataSet.

This is the code I tried:

```
DataRow row = gridView1.GetDataRow(gridView1.GetSelectedRows()[0]);

for (int i = 0; i < connexion.ds.Tables["Auteur"].Rows.Count; i++)
    if (row[0].ToString() == connexion.ds.Tables["Auteur"].Rows[i][0].ToString())
        connexion.ds.Tables["Auteur"].Rows[i].Delete();

for (int i = 0; i < connexion.ds.Tables["AuteurGV"].Rows.Count; i++)
    if (row[0].ToString() == connexion.ds.Tables["AuteurGV"].Rows[i][0].ToString())
        connexion.ds.Tables["AuteurGV"].Rows[i].Delete();

SqlCommandBuilder cmb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
da.Update(connexion.ds, "Auteur");

gridControl1.DataSource = connexion.ds.Tables["AuteurGV"];
```

but it gives me an error in the 6th line:

> *Deleted row information cannot be accessed through the row.*

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
DataRow row = gridView1.GetDataRow(gridView1.GetSelectedRows()[0]); 

string valToDelete = row[0].ToString();

for (int i = 0; i < connexion.ds.Tables["Auteur"].Rows.Count; i++) 
    if (valToDelete == connexion.ds.Tables["Auteur"].Rows[i][0].ToString()) 
         connexion.ds.Tables["Auteur"].Rows[i].Delete(); 

for (int i = 0; i < connexion.ds.Tables["AuteurGV"].Rows.Count; i++) 
    if (valToDelete == connexion.ds.Tables["AuteurGV"].Rows[i][0].ToString()) 
         connexion.ds.Tables["AuteurGV"].Rows[i].Delete(); 

SqlCommandBuilder cmb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da); 
da.Update(connexion.ds); 
gridControl1.DataSource = connexion.ds.Tables["AuteurGV"];
```

The problem is in the second for loop, you have already deleted the row from which you extract the key value to use in the comparison. That's not possible because when the RowState property changes to Delete you cannot use any value from that row.
I have also changed the da.Update call to update all the dataset and not only the Auteur table.

Comment: I solved this problem in the delete button, but I had the same problem when I click on some row in the gridView to extract informations from the dataSet and this is the code I use : `DataRow row = gridView1.GetDataRow(gridView1.GetSelectedRows()[0]);
            for(int i=0; i<connexion.ds.Tables["Auteur"].Rows.Count; i++)
                if (row[0].ToString() == connexion.ds.Tables["Auteur"].Rows[i][0].ToString())
                {
                    nomAuteurBox.Text = connexion.ds.Tables["Auteur"].Rows[i][1].ToString();
                    //......}`

Comment: gridControl and gridView are different controls? Seems that you delete a row using gridView and rebind a gridControl.

Comment: also you delete from the Auteur and AuteurGV tables but update only the Auteur table